# Importing python code then generating different (e.g. java) code from enterprise architect uml diagram

Tags: python, uml, enterprise-architect

I have python modules with standalone functions, from other questions on the web in order to import them to enterprise architect I created global classes grouping the functions and setting them as static methods. I imported them to enterprise architect and it created the classes with the methods, I am also able to see the source code. 
Now, I want to generate code to Java for example. However, I only get the structure, not the new transform code. I even tried to generate the same python code (source code) in a different file and I also get only the structure of the class with its functions but not the code within each function. I am new at this so I have no idea if this is it, or what I have to do to make it work.

Comment: When you imported the python, where did it put the behavioural code? The structure should be relatively easy to generate, the behaviour may be an issue as EA (like many CASE tools) doesn't transform behavioural code from one language to another (not even via an abstract intermediary).

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but behavior(al implementation) in Java and Python are just two different things. Where's the point to "transform" the one into the other?

Comment: I tried putting it in the behaviour initial code and behaviour section. From the behaviour section I get it as comments (which I see helpful to at least describe the logic). You are right, I misunderstood these tools, I thought the generation of different code was possible but it is only for the framework part not for the body. Thank you for your comment @muszeo.

Comment: I get it now @ThomasKilian, this cannot be done. The point was to share the logic in different tools, one uses python which is already developed and the others use different languagues but the same algorithms apply with little changes. I thought, because of the "code generation" name, these tools can do that automatically. But I was wrong :).

Comment: You're welcome :-)

Comment: No worries @Chris, you’d need some kind of compiler to take one language and spit out another. CASE tools don’t do this by and large.